# How to build up a database model from an already existing/working database?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

Okay you may find my question dumb but please read the following.

Actually i'm working in a company and my job is to analyze and query the database in order to produce KPIs.It's a huge company. 
This morning, i connected Oracle SQL Developper to the database. It worked, perfectly. 
 Let's get into the hard part. 
There's no documentation. 
Alright i'm going to build my own documentation. 
...and then i clicked on "Table" in order to expand it and display the table but nothing happens. 
Fine.

I did 
  SELECT Count(*)  FROM all_tables Where table_name like 'T%'

 The result is 5133 tables.

Do you know a good methodology for creating a database model ? 
 By database model i mean  this :

[image: database model]

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer. I also ask the company to provide me the documentation of their database but they told me that the document i'm asking for doesn't exist.

So if you already encountered this kind of problematic, please share how you manage to work in such conditions ? Thanks for you advices

NB: In less than 5 min, i already collected a few downvotes. This is a a professional website, and i'm seeking for professional advices. I'm not asking anyone to do my job, i tried to be the more explicit that i can. Please if something disturb you while reading those lines, tell me and we can discuss about it

Comment: Talk to co-workers and look at existing queries, including those that populate the database.

Answer (score 2):

File > Data Modeler > Import > Data Dictionary

[image]

Use the SQLDev connection

Pick the tables/views you want to build the model for.

If you pick all 5,000 - this will take a lot of time, and consume a lot of memory. You may need to give the JVM more memory to work with a model this large, say 2GB or so. If you can, pick a SUBSET of objects and work with those.

I have step-by-step screenshots [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/10/importing-your-data-dictionary-to-a-new-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler-design/).

Comment: I followed step by step your advices. It was perfectly explained. I'm going to dig more and figure it out. I selected a subset of tables (around 400). 
Thank you for you advices

Comment: good luck on your project - most are under-documented, esp when it comes to the data model